# Count number of character in string ( case-insensitive)

Tags: python

I've been trying to find a way to get the number of a specific character in string using a for loop but I'm unable to make the function case-insensitive.

Any idea what I can do?

```py
def main():
    N = input("Please enter the string to work on:")
    count = 0
    find=input("Please enter a letter that youy want to find in the string entered above:")

    for i in N:
        if i == find:
            count = count + 1

    print ("The character", find, "appeared " +   str( count), "times.")


main()
```

Comment: Put `.lower()` after both input statements.  `N = input("...").lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase the results of the calls to `input()` to ignore casing:

```py
N = input("Please enter the string to work on:")
N = N.lower()
find = input("Please enter a letter that youy want to find in the string entered above:")
find = find.lower()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I've been trying to use the .lower() function but I kept doing it as N.lower() instead of N=N.lower()